# windows sdk 8 installation error 2753

Tags: sdk

I am trying to install the sdk for windows 8 on windows 10 pro and am getting an error 2753.
I already tried to run "regsvr32 vbscript.dll" but it didn't fix my issue.
I need that sdk installed in order to work with another api.
you can find the log here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8qvwixdxiutluq/Windows%20Software%20Development%20Kit_20160608102541.log?dl=0
Cheers

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm having this exact same issue...

Answer (score 7):

If you're still having this issue, it went away after I installed the Windows 8.1 SDK first.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. However, I found a solution to the problem. The error message was: **An error occured while installing « Application Verifier For Windows ». Error code 2753.** I relaunched the installer and when I had to select the features, I unchecked **Application Verifier For Windows**.
The installation was then successfully completed. Hope it helps.